# App crashing when there is no internet connection

Tags: ios, json, cocoa-touch, exception

I am doing an iPhone app for news. I am getting news data through `ASIHTTPRequest` and parsing with `JSONKit`. It's working fine when connected to the Internet, however if WiFi connection is off I am getting the following exception and the app crashes:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'The jsonData argument is NULL.'

Here is my code:

```
- (id)objectWithData: (NSData *)jsonData error: (NSError **)error
{
    if(jsonData == NULL)
    {
        [NSException raise:NSInvalidArgumentException format:@"The jsonData argument is NULL."];
    }

    return([self objectWithUTF8String:(const unsigned char *)[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] error:error]);
}
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I dont understand.. You are manually raising that exception, so what do you expect? Of course its going to throw it. Please post your return from your web request.

Comment: how do i handle this situation

Comment: Well, instead of throwing an exception you may just display an Altert that informs the user that his operation requires some internet access. Then you could return nil instead of some json bytes and ensure that the calling function processes the nil value accordingly.

Comment: It is OK to through exceptions if you are handling it with try-catch block as i wrote below.

Comment: `ASIHTTPRequest` development has been abandoned.  The developer is [recommending alternatives](http://allseeing-i.com/%5Brequest_release%5D).  If this is a new app you are developing, you should consider those alternatives.  Otherwise, when some future iOS release breaks `ASIHTTPRequest` you're going to have a project on your hands dealing with the internals of a library that is no longer maintained.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

After including the files/code from the sample code in your appDelegate, create an instance of appDelegate in the class you want to check internet and use the following:

```
- (id)objectWithData:(NSData *)jsonData error:(NSError **)error
{
    YourAppDelegate *appDelegate = (YourAppDelegate * )[[UIApplication SharedApplication]delegate];

    if (![appDelegate checkNetworkConnectionAndWarnUser:YES])
    {
        NSLog(@"No internet");
    }
    else
    {
        return([self objectWithUTF8String:(const unsigned char *)[jsonData bytes] length:[jsonData length] error:error]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use cmnd+shift+F to find the place where you are using illegal argument, you should normally not get to that place if the request failed.

It seems like you are trying to process the request result regardless of it's status, but you need to make nil/NULL check for the received data anyway. The exception you throw must be caught and processed with `@try - @catch`.